# Memory issue when trying to start a minecraft server via a python script

Tags: java, python, multithreading, memory-management, batch-file

Okay iv been working on a hand full of tool to help maintain a large number a of game servers hosted on a single computer. What i'm am doing is lunching a .bat file from a python script. That bat file sets the servers prams like max memory and things of that nature. I open and run the .bat file with the following function.

```
def StartServer(path,file):
    if file not in MK.keys():

        l = Popen(file, cwd=path)
        MK[file]=l
        stdout, stderr = l.communicate()
    else:
        MK[file].terminate()
```

this function is called in one of two ways the
1st way is to start the program.

```
thread.start_new_thread( StartServer, (path,File, ) )
```

2nd the close the program

```
StartServer(path,File)
```

StartServer see the reentry and terminates the specified program...
and this works great for programs that need very little ram, like a bat file such as

```
@echo Hello world.
@pause
```

however when trying to allocate more ram for a java program such as,

```
@ECHO OFF
SET BINDIR=%~dp0
CD /D "%BINDIR%"
"%ProgramFiles%\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -Xmx4096M -Xms4096M -jar Minecraft_RKit.jar user:password
PAUSE
```

I receive a memory error from the BAT file as follows. this is from the bat file not from the python side

```
Invalid mat heap size: -Xmx4096M
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Error: Could not create java virtual machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Note: I prefer to use both python and the bat file thank you in advance!

Comment: Just a guess, you're running 32-bit Python so `%ProgramFiles%` points to 32-bit Java?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to start a 32-bit JVM, giving it a heap size that is too large for a 32-bit architecture.  The maximum heap size is something less than 3Gb for a 32-bit JVM.  The actual limit depends on the OS (which determines how much of the address space is made available to applications) and on how much non-heap memory is used by the JVM.

Either reduce the max heap size, or switch to a 64-bit JVM (and a 64-bit OS).

Comment: Yup.  You were most likely using a 64bit JVM too.